# Difference Between find and Where with Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I wouldn't think there is a difference when it comes to active record and finding data.

Here are my models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shows
end

class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I use the rails console I can do the following and it works.

```
u = User.find(1)
u.shows
```

It gives me all the shows for that user.

However when I do

```
u = User.where("username = ?", "percent20")
u.shows # this is doesn't work gives me a now instance error
```

I get the same user and relevant information, but not the relationship. The only problem I can see is maybe I am doing something wrong because there is some difference between where and find.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is not the relationship.

```
 u = User.find(1)
```

returns one User

```
 #return a Set of users. In your case its only one user.
 u = User.where("username = ?", "percent20")
```

The result type is ActiveRecord::Relation --> [User, User, User]

use e.g. first to get the first User

```
 #returns the first user
 u = User.where("username = ?", "percent20").first
```

u.class.name
=> "User"

Comment: I feel really dumb after reading this. I knew this, grrrrrrr. Am marking this as the answer because of the verbosity of the answer. Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 5):

User.find(1) is retrieving a specific record with its ID, whereas User.where("username = ?", "percent20") is retrieving the set of records that match the condition.

Try:

```
u = User.where("username = ?", "percent20").first
u.shows
```

Answer (score 3):

The **where** is method that returns an array of objects. So, in your case try

```
u.each { |user| user.shows }
```