# Difference between "where" and "find"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is almost answered in [Difference Between find and Where with Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213358/difference-between-find-and-where-with-relationships) but not quite. (Notice how I subtly changed the question title!)
I do the query

```
a = Libation.where("user_id = 1" )   # gets 10 records
b = a.sum("count * weight")          # Get right answer
c = Libation.where("user_id = 2" )   # gets 8 records
d = c.sum("count * weight")          # Get right answer
```

Now I do

```
e = Libation.all                # gets 18 records, good
f = e.sum("count * weight")     # BOOM! I get

NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for #<Libation:0x3b91e88>):
```

Nuts. I tried to find relevant docs, but found little. Or I am not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#where` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, which you can them perform additional methods on (such as `#sum`). However, `#all` executes the query returns an array of results, so when you do `e.sum(...)` you're trying to perform `#sum` on an `Array` object rather than an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

You might try using `#scoped` instead:

```
e = Libation.scoped
f = e.sum("count * weight")
```

Comment: thanks, very nicely explained. about time i read up on scopes.

Answer (score 1):

doing `Model.where(condition)` returns an Active Relation, so when you do `a = Libation.where(...)` you don't get an array, but an Active Relation on which you can chain other methods as you do below `b = a.sum(...)`

`Libation.all` returns an array of objects, actually executing the query to the database (by using where, the query is called only when you try to iterate for example over the returned result)