# How to create a new Post through a User?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following User and Post relationships:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :posts
end


class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  belongs_to :user
end
```

I am trying to create a new Post through a User, but I get an error. I am not sure why:

```
1.9.3-p392 :001 > @user = User.where(:id => 1)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1
 => [#<User id: 1, email: "test@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$ltpBpN0gMzOGULVtMxqgueQHat1DLkY.Ino3E1QoO2nI...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 6, current_sign_in_at: "2013-03-04 05:33:46", last_sign_in_at: "2013-03-03 22:18:17", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2013-03-02 03:41:48", updated_at: "2013-03-04 05:33:46", avatar_file_name: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil>] 
1.9.3-p392 :002 > @user.posts.create(:content => "This is the content")
NoMethodError: undefined method `posts' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x000000024ca868>
```

Comment: use `@user = User.where(:id => 1).first`

Comment: try using @user = user.find_by_id(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```rb
User.where(:id => 1)
```

does not give you a model instance, but a [relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html). Hence the `NoMethodError` on ActiveRecord::**Relation**.

Change your first line to

```
User.find(1)
```

and you're fine.

Comment: Please see my revised answer: Don't use `User.where...` at all but `User.find...`

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between `where` and `find` in the ActiveRecord Relationships.

The query:

`@user = User.where(:id => 1)` is giving your the array hash.

So when you do something like `@user.posts` for the above query, it gives error of `NoMethodError on ActiveRecord::Relation` as there is no such post associated with this hash. So in order to convert it into the user whose id is 1, you do like this:

```
@user = User.where(:id => 1).first
```

or

```
@user = User.find(:id => 1)
```

Both will give you the user whose id is 1 (only one record) and then you can use this:

```
@user.posts
```

The above will give the associated posts of user with id 1.

Then you can do:

```
@user.posts.create(:content => "Post of user 1")
```

So what you are trying to do is actually giving you the hash (set of users) but actually you want only one user to create the relevant post.

Also, See the [difference between find and where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213358/difference-between-find-and-where-with-relationships).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
@user = User.where(:id => 1).shift
@user.posts.create(:content => "This is the content")
```

**OR**

```
@user = User.find(1)
@user.posts.create(:content => "This is the content")
```